# jQuery ajax escapes my data, how can I prevent this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, escaping

Let's say I have a form input and when a user enters the word "TEST". I take that form value and send it to an API with ajax:

```
var form_value = $('input').val();
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            form_value: form_value,
        }
    })
```

and in the file `ajax_handler.php`, the first thing I do is a `var_dump($_POST['form_value']);`.

The result then becomes: `string(8) "\"TEST\""`. Which is n escpaed version of what the user originally wrote. Why? I have php magic quotes setting turned OFF in the ini file so it's not that. It seems that the AJAX auto escapes it.

How can I prevent that the jQuery ajax escapes my value? I want it unaltered.

Comment: try  dataType: 'text',

Comment: Umm, you need to parse it e.g. `json_decode($_POST['form_value'], true)`

Comment: None of these suggestions worked, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var form_value = $('input').val();
var rawData={"form_value":form_value}; //your desired format, however you want not to be altered
var finData= JSON.stringify(rawData);
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_handler.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: finData
})
```

Comment: But the function JSON.stringify adds slashes before the quotes.